# "no such file or directory,crypto.app" error RabbitMQ on windows 10

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I installed rabbitmq and erlang, but whatever I do, it doesn't work.

```
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQServer\rabbitmq_server-3.11.10\sbin>rabbitmq-server.bat start
{"init terminating in do_boot",{error,{crypto,{"no such file or directory","crypto.app"}}}}
init terminating in do_boot ({error,{crypto,{no such file or directory,crypto.app}}})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

C:\Program Files\RabbitMQServer\rabbitmq_server-3.11.10\sbin>rabbitmqctl.bat
** (throw) {:error, {:missing_dependencies, [:crypto, :public_key], [:amqp10_client, :cowboy, :cowlib, :jose, :rabbitmq_aws, :rabbitmq_management, :rabbitmq_management_agent, :rabbitmq_shovel, :rabbitmq_trust_store]}}
    (rabbit 3.11.10) rabbit_plugins.erl:234: :rabbit_plugins.ensure_dependencies/1
    (rabbitmqctl 3.11.0) lib/rabbitmq/cli/plugins/plugins_helpers.ex:47: RabbitMQ.CLI.Plugins.Helpers.list/1
    (rabbitmqctl 3.11.0) lib/rabbitmq/cli/core/command_modules.ex:83: RabbitMQ.CLI.Core.CommandModules.plugin_modules/1
    (rabbitmqctl 3.11.0) lib/rabbitmq/cli/core/command_modules.ex:54: RabbitMQ.CLI.Core.CommandModules.load_commands/2
    (rabbitmqctl 3.11.0) lib/rabbitmq/cli/core/command_modules.ex:33: RabbitMQ.CLI.Core.CommandModules.load/1
    (rabbitmqctl 3.11.0) lib/rabbitmq/cli/ctl/commands/help_command.ex:232: RabbitMQ.CLI.Ctl.Commands.HelpCommand.commands_description/1
    (rabbitmqctl 3.11.0) lib/rabbitmq/cli/ctl/commands/help_command.ex:101: RabbitMQ.CLI.Ctl.Commands.HelpCommand.all_usage/1
    (rabbitmqctl 3.11.0) lib/rabbitmqctl.ex:42: RabbitMQCtl.exec_command/2
```

I installed both with "run as administrator". When it didn't work, I uninstalled and reinstalled it, but it still didn't work

Environment variables:

ERLANG_HOME  ==>  C:\Program Files\Erlang OTP

RABBITMQ_SERVER  ==>  C:\Program Files\RabbitMQServer\rabbitmq_server-3.11.10

in path:
%ERLANG_HOME%\bin\erl.exe

%RABBITMQ_SERVER%\sbin

erlang == 25.2,
rabbitmq == 3.11.10

Comment: I would install Erlang and check whether crypto can start with `crypto:start().` command in the erl.exe shell. Somewhere I saw that crypto requires openssl to be installed within the operating system. Further browse for [google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=erlang+windows+missing+crypto) results might give a hint. Please also check that you have an Erlang package that actually includes crypto, not all has.

Answer (score 1):

`RABBITMQ_SERVER` is not a supported environment variable.

You should un-install RabbitMQ and Erlang, **remove all environment variables you have set pertaining to RabbitMQ**

- `ERLANG_HOME` - not necessary
- `RABBITMQ_SERVER` - not supported

...then install Erlang and RabbitMQ from an administrative command prompt.